# How to .SetValue(string, object) for context menu in internet explorer?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I am trying to add new entries to the internet explorer context menu.  I want to use the default menu and according do this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I want to use the value 0x1.  When I type:

```
key.SetValue("Contexts", 0x1)
```

into visual studio, I get the error "Comma, ")", or a valid expression continuation expected."

It works in this example using c#:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2618576

but in this example using vb.net: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBCustomIEContextMenu-913227d7/sourcecode?fileId=22702&pathId=537448198

They use:

```
ieMenuExtKey.SetValue("Contexts", &H2)
```

does anyone know how I can get this to work in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x` is a prefix for hexadecimal numbers. VB.NET uses `&H` instead. So your code should be `key.SetValue("Contexts", &H1)`. Because `1` has same value in both hexadecimal and decimal systems, you  can delete `&H` - `key.SetValue("Contexts", 1)` is fine.

Comment: I had a hunch that this was the answer but thank you for actually explaining to me what was happening!